# looking for a good random algorithm

Tags: javascript, math, random

I'm not satisfied with Math.random() from javascript. I would like to create a function that generates random numbers. What I need is that if I generate 100.000 numbers from 1 to 100, the frequencies that the numbers appear must be as close as possible. The minimum frequency a number appears to be as close as possible to the maximum frequency.
Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: or simply: uniform distribution. BTW do you need discrete or continuous ...?

Comment: are you looking for a shuffling?

Comment: I need to call a function doSomething(), and each time that function is called, a local variable into that function must have a random value between 1 and N (N is variable).

Comment: What is "as close as possible"? If the results are too even, does that make the outcome more predictable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably implement [MT19937](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) in JS, which is a quite capable algorithm suitable for a wide range of applications (not cryptography, though!).

Answer (score 1):

start with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation), if that doesn't give you any clues I'd recommend Donald Knuths **TAOCP** Volume 2 - Seminumerical Algorithms, chapter 3

Comment: TAOCP is [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Computer-Programming-Volumes-Boxed/dp/0201485419).